# Is it possible to do geocoding in cronjob only?

Tags: cron-job, geocoding

I'd want to only do the geocoding in batch mode, because otherwise, it's too slow for my use case (petition signatures with dozen of signatures per second).

Is there a way to use the geocoding via the cronjob but disable it from the api call (contact.create)?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you can pass skip_geocode to the params of 'fixAddress' a number of ways (such as injecting it with tpl override or javascript).

Check CRM/Core/BAO/Address.php line 381-382.

```
// check if geocode should be skipped (can be forced with an optional parameter through the api)
$skip_geocode = (isset($params['skip_geocode']) && $params['skip_geocode']) ? TRUE : FALSE;
```

Leave geocoding enabled so the cron process completes it, but it is skipped when accessing via web.